# Rails Ransack - how display empty result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I've integrated Ransack into my Rails app, I use it via ajax post, soso in t he `index.html.erb` it uses the `_partner.html.erb`
But when I get back empty search result, I would like to achieve display a "No result" text.

I've tried it this way(in `index.js.erb`):

```
$('#partners_list').html('<% if @partners %> <%= escape_javascript render(@partners) %> <% else %><li class="collection-item">No result</li><% end %>');
$('nav.pagination').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@partners, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

But this is not work, cause if there aren't any search result it will generate this javascript code:

```
$('nav.pagination').html('  ');
$('nav.pagination').html('');
```

This will not insert any `<li>` elements into the `<ul>`
(`index.html.erb`)

```
<ul id="partners_list" class="collection margin-0-minus-15 z-depth-2">
   <%= render @partners %>
</ul>
```

(I've tried handle here in the `index.html.erb` too, but it seems if there is no search result then the `@partners` does not exist... because the `<%= debug(@partners) %>` will not show nothing on the view if the search result is empty)

This is my **action**:

```
def index
    @search = Partner.where(is_active: true).search(params[:q])
    @partners = @search.result.includes(:user, :county).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
  end
```

How can I achieve when I the back-end searching response with empty result, then the application display an "Empty result" text?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried with if else statement outside the html('')?

```
<% if @partners.any? %>
  $('#partners_list').html("<%= j render(@partners) %>")
<% else %>
  $('#partners_list').html("<li class="collection-item">No result</li>")
<% end %>
```

Comment: Of course, I've tried it. But it did not work. I have tried it in the index.html.erb too.